# How to fix no such file - ios/platform_www/cordova.js

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

When I run ionic cordova prepare ios on my Macbook Air, I get the following error:

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/myUserID/Ionic/myApp/platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova.js

I was previously able to run this command but after moving my latest code over (from Windows machine), now suddenly there is an issue.

Any ideas on where to troubleshoot this?  Or what causes it?

Comment: Maybe try removing and readding the platform? That looks like a messed up windows path to me.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following commands in order:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android --save
ionic cordova platform add android@latest --save
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the project is missing `cordova.js` on platforms folder & while building it missing some important files , So you can run below commands for respective platforms.

> Android

```
ionic cordova platform rm android --save
ionic cordova platform add android --save
```

> iOS

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios --save
ionic cordova platform add ios --save
```

It should work..